# How to get URL param in last Angular 2 version

Tags: angular

I was reading different posts about it but I couldn't found a solution that works on final Angular 2 version.

I load my web app with:

http://127.0.0.1/login?auth=myTokenValue

I've got in my app.routes.ts

```
  { path: 'login/:auth', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
```

and my login.component.ts with:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.parent.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.parentRouteId = params["auth"];
      console.log(this.parentRouteId);
    });
```

But it always shows on console a

> undefined

Note:

I've also tested in app.component.ts this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.parentRouteId = params["auth"];
      console.log(this.parentRouteId);
    });
  }
```

---

**RESOLVED:**

app.routes.ts

```
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
{ path: '', component: LoginComponent }
```

login.component.ts

```
  constructor(private router:Router) {
    var param = router.parseUrl(router.url).queryParams["auth"];
    console.log("Extracted value: ")
    console.log(param);
  }
```

I use this url

```
http://127.0.0.1:4200/#/login?auth=tokenvaluetoread
```

on web browser

Comment: /login?auth=myTokenValue is not 'login/:auth'

Comment: One sec will try you route

Comment: and how should I define the route?

Comment: I have updated my answer check it

Answer (score 1):

This is because of plus before params

```
 this.parentRouteId = +params["auth"];
```

So remove and be happY :)

Second problem is your routing

```
 { path: 'login/:auth', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
```

First route is actually is not working because it expect url to be **login/myTokenValue** so it falling to second route which is "" so that is why you are getting null when you try to read params.

To get token you can make right url like this http://127.0.0.1/login/myTokenValue or [use Router](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/UrlSegment-class.html)

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route: Router ) {
    var param = route.parseUrl(route.url).queryParams["auth"];
   }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

In addition take a look at [ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/ActivatedRoute-interface.html)

Comment: Thank you, but now it shows "undefined", I think I've got any other problem (I've updated my question code)

Comment: @user7170396 have you tried http://127.0.0.1:4200/#/login/myTokenValue ?

Comment: It's showing the same for me, perhaps it would be a problem whith main route, it's redirecting to root and I'm losing the params. I've paste my code above.

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: I'm using 2.1.2 version of angular

Comment: are you using angular-cli?

Comment: Try to comment route with **

Comment: yes, it was the first I've tried but it's the same. It couldn't be so difficult to get the route param but I can't find the problem

Comment: What you see in dev tools console? it should print exceptions

Comment: By the way please update you question with how you configure route

Comment: Do you have imports   RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true }) ?

Comment: I have imported on my app.module.ts with RouterModule.forRoot(routes)

Comment: Resolved, I've updated the first question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's showing exactly the same for me but it could be possible a problem in other place:

When I use

/login/myTokenValue or /login?auth=myTokenValue

the browser change the URL to http://127.0.0.1:4200/#/

and I get an undefined value.

My login component has:

```
constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute, private router:Router, private userService:UserService, private constants:Constants, private paytimeIdle:PaytimeIdle) {    
    var param = router.parseUrl(router.url).queryParams["auth"];
    console.log(param);
  }


  /* These are not neccesary at this moment */
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.parent.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.parentRouteId = params["auth"];
      console.log(this.parentRouteId);
    });
```

and my app.routes.ts

```
export const routes = [      
  { path: 'login/:auth', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent }
];
```

and my app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
 ...
 imports [
     ...
     RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
 ]
```

Thanks